# Why do Webp images not load in VScode but they load in Repl.it?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, web, webp

Why do Webp images display this error on VScode:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shmjW.png)

But they work fine on another IDE such as Repl.it? I did not change anything. The paths to the pictures are the exact same but for some reason the images work fine on repl.it but on VScode they display that error. Anyone know why this happens?

I cant share any code since its a whole project but to basically link an image, I do this both on VScode and Repl.it: `./assets/img/image.webp`

`assets` is a folder in the root

Can VScode render Webp images or is that ability not supported as of right now?

Comment: I don't know for the problem itself but I tryed to open a webp image in vscode and the render works

Comment: Do you have any extension installed?